# Proof verification. Algebraic topology

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, proof-writing

Proof verification:

> Let $(X,A)$ be a pair of topological spaces and suppose that $A$ is
>   path-connected. If $j:(X,\emptyset)\to (X,A)$, $x\mapsto j(x)=x$ then
>   $j_*:H_1(X)\to H_1(X,A)$ is surjective.

Let $T+S_1(X)$ be an element of $Z_1(X,A)$. If we choose $T'=T$ then:
$$j_*[T]=[T+S_1(X)]$$
So, it is clear that $j_*$ is surjective

What is wrong with my reasoning? (I did not use that $A$ is path connected)

Comment: What are $T$ and $S_1(X)$?

Comment: Just answering with a guess on the terminologies, I think your $T^\prime$ is not necessarily in $Z_1(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to approach this using the long exact sequence of a pair $(X,A)$ (for reduced homology):
$$\cdots\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\tilde{H}_1(A)\xrightarrow{\ i \ }\tilde{H}_1(X)\xrightarrow{\ j \ }\tilde{H}_1(X,A)\xrightarrow{\ \partial \ }\tilde{H}_0(A)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\cdots$$
Note that $\tilde{H}_1(X) = H_1(X)$ and $\tilde{H}_1(X,A)=H_1(X,A)$. What does $A$ being path connected imply here?